# Does Origin have groups and events à la Steam Community?

Tags: origin

(Unnecessary preamble.) Given yesterday's failure of the L4D2 Game On, we decided to change to Battlefield 3 to [put this fancy server of ours to the test.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/3134#3134) I made the relevant Steam event but... that doesn't really help, does it?

Does Origin have groups and events like Steam does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not.

Origin doesn't really support any of the features that Steam does in terms of profile and networking.

Comment: So right now all it does is provide access to games that EA made Origin-Exclusive and quite possibly [snoop a bit more around your hard drive than you'd like it to](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/js51f/ea_origin_spyware_issue_silently_boycotting_will/)?

Comment: @Shadur Pretty much.